# Playing multiple songs from ipod library

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

From your app is it possible to play multiple songs from the iPod library at the same time. Or of not is there a way to save the songs in the iphone sandbox and then play them together as normal sound files? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to go through `MPMusicPlayerController` Class Reference. It will help you to play songs from iPod Library

[Here's the link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)